# Why is "this.getAttribute()" returning null?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working with dynamic fields and I want to sort the fields into a JS object. But when I call `getAttribute`, it returns null.

Here, `q2` is the ID that I want to print off for testing. It prints off the value successfully (and its children for some reason), but `getAttribute` is null.

```
<div class="input-group" data-question-id = nVar id = q2>
----
$( "#qForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
    $('#q2 input').each(function () {
    console.log(this.value);
    console.log(this.getAttribute("data-question-id"))
```

`nVar` is a variable ID that I iterate when I add a field.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#q2 input')` doesn't point to the element that has the `data-question-id` attribute. Assuming the `input` is a direct child, you need to use `this.parentNode` instead:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#q2 input').each(function() {
    console.log(this.value);
    console.log(this.parentNode.getAttribute("data-question-id"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group" data-question-id="5" id="q2">
  <input type="text" value="hello world!">
</div>
```

Note that it's generally considered better not to mix JS and jQuery constructs where you can remain consistent. For example, staying with jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#q2 input').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
    console.log($(this).parent().data("question-id"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group" data-question-id="5" id="q2">
  <input type="text" value="hello world!">
</div>
```

or in pure JS:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('#q2 input').forEach(function(el) {
    console.log(el.value);
    console.log(el.parentNode.getAttribute("data-question-id"));
  });
};
```

```html
<div class="input-group" data-question-id="5" id="q2">
  <input type="text" value="hello world!">
</div>
```

Comment: What could be the reason behind mixing jQuery and vanilla JS in these few lines of code!

Comment: @Mamun good question - you'd have to ask OP that. I was just following their existing code pattern..

Comment: Well, you can say *existing bad code pattern* and you can easily suggest him to the better one.